# Log forging and log integrity with Winston

Tags: node.js, logging, winston

I am developing a NodeJS server and I am looking for solution against log forging.  I found a popular tool, [Winston](https://github.com/winstonjs/winston) and I implemented it in my server.

However, I since I couldn't find it in their GitHub page or on their website, I want to ask how does it handle log forging and the logs' integrity in general? Does it have a built-in strategy or are there extra steps necessary in order to do this?

Comment: Did you find a solution for the same ?

Comment: We went with Winston anyways. However, I cannot remember how far we went into this investigation.